# Facebook iOS API getting all liked pages of a user

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm not talking about getting all the users who like a particular page. Instead, I want to get all the facebook pages liked by a particular user who login to my app using the Facebook login.

This is like Tinder, where I can know, that user like the same page as the page I like, for example.

I'm not familiar with Facebook ios API at all. Perusing the docs I don't see it under user, I don't seem to see it under pages. I don't know where to look.

Any pointer appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you looking for iOS code or for graph API call you would wrap in iOS?

Comment: iOS code I guess. So I guess what daniellarsson gives me is considered iOS code, then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#likes) has a `likes` method that you can call, that returns all the pages that a user has liked. You will need `user_likes` or `friends_likes` permissions.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/PROFILE_ID/likes" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(
                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                      id result,
                      NSError *error
                  ) {
                      /* handle the result */
                  }];
```

If you are new to the Graph API, I suggest looking around in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to get you started on things.